# What is the state of Rittenhouse following the finale?

Tags: timeless

In the two-part finale of *Timeless* named “The Miracle of Christmas”, Emma Whitmore is killed. What is the state of Rittenhouse following that?  Benjamin Cahill presumably returned to custody after helping rat her out, but there are still others, right? I mean, there’s still people like the guy who didn’t remember that Jennifer existed, and I can’t imagine Connor Mason and Denise Christopher rounding up everyone by themselves.

So does Rittenhouse still exist after all that? Or was it somehow disbanded?

Comment: Answer to this would be highly speculative as Rittenhouse is not just **ONE** family but a group of families with vested interests. So I guess will have to wait up till someone steal Time Machine designs from that little girl in the end.

Comment: @Rahul So you’re saying that Rittenhouse is still around then? They seem to act as though they aren’t around in 2023 (certainly not like their future selves say they are when they hand them the journal).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @rahul:

> ...Rittenhouse is not just ONE family but a group of families with vested interests.

Let's add a couple more observations.

- Benjamin Cahill might be in custody, but that doesn't mean that he is
  no longer involved in Rittenhouse, and it's certainly no indication
  that Rittenhouse has been dissolved. After all, he tells Emma that he knows 
  where all of the Rittenhouse property is and had to go to many of them before he found her. So their assets aren't dried up, Emma just didn't know about all of them.
- Lucy is Rittenhouse Royalty. Could we possibly speculate that if she
  would have just claimed her place in the hierarchy she would have
  been able to call the shots, or at least influence them, and put an end to it?
- Emma was shot at the end, but that doesn't mean that she died. Hello,
  loose end.
- The upgraded lifeboat still exists, under guard, but totally
  functional. Specifically so that they can use it if someone creates
  another time machine.
- And yes, that little girl at the end.  Perhaps she is the daughter of
  the child that Wyatt delivered as they were rushing to evacuate? 
  Certainly trying to save the mother and child (in Korea) changed their history
  from what it would have been...

So, Rittenhouse is most likely hindered, but gone? Doubtful.

Comment: Can you speak a bit more about there being multiple families active with Rittenhouse? You focus on Cahill, Emma, and the possibility of future time travel. But the show presents them as *the* Rittenhouse, and there absence makes it seem as though Rittenhouse is gone.

Comment: They elude to conquering Rittenhouse, but when Lucy tells her Mother about Rittenhouse (S01E16), her Mother tells her that she is 'Rittenhouse Royalty' that she (and Lucy's father) both came from strong Rittenhouse families. That reinforces that there are multiple family lines in Rittenhouse. Also the Rittenhouse meeting of 1954 (same episode) shows a few dozen people at the meeting, clearly not all from one family line.

Comment: "Perhaps she is the daughter of the child that Wyatt delivered as they were rushing to evacuate? Certainly trying to save the mother and child (in Korea) changed their history from what it would have been..." Unless that baby girl joined them in the mothership, there is no way that someone born in 1950 would be a teenager in 2023. However, she does seem to be the same girl that Rufus talks to at the science fair at the end.

Comment: No, "the daughter of the child"... She would have been the daughter of the girl born in korea, not the girl that was born during the Korean evacuation, the daughter of that child.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment,

> Answer to this would be highly speculative as Rittenhouse is not just ONE family but a group of families with vested interests. So I guess will have to wait up till someone steal Time Machine designs from that little girl in the end.

I would like to add a point here that Rittenhouse is still around in 2023, maybe a little shocked because Lucy's father who earlier seemed to be committed to cause, ratted out Emma for saving Lucy and mothership eventually fell into hands of Feds.

After destruction of mothership, *lifeboat* from future which is advanced version of earlier one is under armed surveillance.

Now without a time machine Rittenhouse is paralyzed and can't do much in present.

A cliffhanger where that teen girl seem to come up with similar idea of *Flux Capacitor* and time machine as of Rufus might be lead for next season.

Comment: Except that there is no next season. The Christmas double episode/movie was the series finale (not a season finale). bummer, but true